# Change unit in Split tool on ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: coordinate-system, vector, arcgis-pro, splitting, units

I'm working on a project with a CRS in meters, map units and display units are also in meters, but `Split` tool (from Modify features) is in feet:

[image]

Is there a way to change unit to split based in a distance in meters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ArcGIS Pro help](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/split-a-feature.htm) from `Split` in Modify Features pane says (emphasis mine).

> Specify a distance
>
> Specifying a distance allows you to divide a polyline feature into two features or multiple features with equal or varying distances using the **default project units**. You can choose from which end of the feature to calculate the values.

So you need to set the 'Location units' as meters as well. See [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/map-units-location-units-and-display-units.htm):

1. Go to the 'Options' dialog.
2. Select the 'Units' tab.
3. Click 'Select Unit Code' and choose one from the list of available units.